# How do I read the length of array loaded from req.session in nodejs?

Tags: arrays, node.js, session, express

My code looks like this in my post request:

```
var titles = [];
        movies.forEach(function(movie) {

            // If title exists in array, dont push.
            if(titles.indexOf(movie.title) > -1){
                console.log('skipped duplicate title of '+movie.title);

            }
            else{
                titles.push(movie.title);
                console.log('pushed '+movie.title);
            }
        });

        req.session.titles = titles;
        console.log(req.session.titles);
```

and my get request looks like this:

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    var arr = req.session.titles;
    if(arr.length > 0) {
    //do something
}
```

But I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at Object`

My server.js looks like this. I don't think sessions are working tho.. What am I doing wrong?
I think I had sessions working before and I have all the packages installed..

My req.session.titles is empty as thought in the comments..

```
// server.js

// set up ======================================================================
// get all the tools we need
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 3003;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
var fs       = require('fs');
var morgan       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');
//var Parse = require('../app/models/parse');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// set up our express application
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // get information from html forms
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({
  secret: 'hakunamatata',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

// set the default tmpdir for uploads (IMPORTANT)
process.env.TMPDIR = './tmp';

//load all files in models dir
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/app/models').forEach(function(filename) {
    if (~filename.indexOf('js')) require(__dirname + '/app/models/' + filename)
});

// launch ======================================================================
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Well, it is clear that arr is undefined, and obliviously req.session.titles is undefined. Debug what inside req.session and check if your sessions works at all. do you do app.use(sessions), app.use(cookie_parser)? Where do you store your sessions?

Comment: Updated with some code, do you know what could be the cause?

Comment: It's not clear to me where in your code you're running that code that populates the titles array.

Comment: I am running it in routes.js and I have the code above. It is the part where I run titles.push(movie.title), then I save it to session with req.session.titles = titles. Which is the array of titles from the omdb api for nodejs.

Comment: When im looking at the terminal, I have the console.log command executing before I get the result.. So I probably redirect the page before all results are downloaded from the API, is this possible? In my get request I have a console.log that says "here comes session"+req.session.titles. And I see that before the print in the post request containing the resulting movies that should execute before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see one error definitely in line var titles = [];
Here you actually drop title every post request. What you should do is to write

```
var titles = req.session.titles || [];
```

Also you executing app.use(cookieParser()); twice.

Don't think that fixing those two errs will fix the problem, but anyway they there.

Comment: I should drop it every post request ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in my sessions but rather in the get request executing before the omdb api is done reading data to the session variable. So the session variable was not set before I tried to access it.

I used callback function to solve this.

Link to that question and how I solved it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258462/trying-to-implement-callback-or-some-way-to-wait-until-my-get-request-is-done).