# Trying to implement callback, or some way to wait until my get request is done. This is in node.js express

Tags: node.js, express, callback

Im trying to implement some way to stop my code to redirect me before I get the response from the omdb api I am using.

My function for making a search for a movie and saving all titles in a session looks like this:

```
app.post('/search', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

        function getMovies(arg, callback){
            console.log('In getMovies');

            console.log('searching for '+arg);

            omdb.search(arg, function(err, movies) {
                if(err) {
                    return console.error(err);
                }

                if(movies.length < 1) {
                    return console.log('No movies were found!');
                }   

                var titles = [];
                movies.forEach(function(movie) {

                    // If title exists in array, dont push.
                    if(titles.indexOf(movie.title) > -1){
                        console.log('skipped duplicate title of '+movie.title);

                    }
                    else{
                        titles.push(movie.title);
                        console.log('pushed '+movie.title);
                    }
                });

                // Saves the titles in a session
                req.session.titles = titles;
                console.log(req.session.titles);    
            });

            // Done with the API request
            callback();
        }

        var title = req.body.title;

        getMovies(title, function() {

            console.log('Done with API request, redirecting to GET SEARCH');
            res.redirect('/search');

        });

    });
```

However I dont know if I implement callback in the right way, because I think there can be a problem with the api request actually executing before the callback, but not finishing before. And therefor the callback is working..

So I just want 2 things from this question. Does my callback work? And what can I do if a callback won't solve this problem?

Thankful for all answers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
callback();
```

To, like this

```
omdb.search(arg, function(err, movies) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

    if (movies.length < 1) {
        return console.log('No movies were found!');
    }

    var titles = [];
    movies.forEach(function(movie) {

        // If title exists in array, dont push.
        if (titles.indexOf(movie.title) > -1) {
            console.log('skipped duplicate title of ' + movie.title);

        } else {
            titles.push(movie.title);
            console.log('pushed ' + movie.title);
        }
    });

    // Saves the titles in a session
    req.session.titles = titles;
    callback();
});
```

*omdb.search* is asynchronous function that's why *callback* executed before omdb.search